# Why is this probability not sums up to one, wired made up function, please enlighten me.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value

[image]

**This is an assignment question, not attempting to fish for a direct solution**.

Below is my confusion.

I don't understand why there are $3^3=27$ such functions from $D$ to $\{1,2,3\}$, but each of the functions has probability $P(\{f\})=\frac{3}{72}=\frac{1}{24}$. The probabilities are not summing to $1$.

Appreciate any comments and help.

**Attempts**

We have $1,7,19$ such functions satisfy $\max_{x \in D}f(x)=1,2,3$ respectively.

$X(f) = f(\text{apple}) + f(\text{orange})$ can takes values from $2$ to $6$, so the expectation of each will be

\begin{align}
E(\max f = 1) &= 2 \left( \frac{1}{72} \right) \\
E(\max f = 2) &= \bigg[4 \left( \frac{2}{7} \right) + 3 \left( \frac{4}{7} \right) + 2 \left( \frac{1}{7} \right) \bigg] \frac{14}{72} \\
E(\max f = 3) &= \bigg[2 \left( \frac{1}{19} \right) + 3 \left( \frac{2}{19} \right) + 4 \left( \frac{7}{19} \right) + 5 \left( \frac{6}{19} \right) + 6 \left( \frac{3}{19} \right) \bigg] \frac{57}{72}
\end{align}

and therefore

$$
E(X) = E(\max f = 1) + E(\max f = 2) + E(\max f = 3) \approx 4.1389
$$

Comment: Hint: How many functions have a max of $1$?

Comment: @quasi only $1$? $1$ assigns to all elements in $D$

Comment: So for that function, $P(\{f\})$ is equal to ??

Comment: And how many $f$ have maximum value $2$? How many $3$?

Comment: aha, I see,  Thank you guys so much !

Comment: Hi , I just post my attempt and much appreciate it if you guys can help me to verify that.  Cheers